# Android google map landforms

Tags: android, maps

I've been succeded to import google maps on an android application. My question is, how can I import map with landforms? For exemple, mountain, rivers, plains, hills. I did only for street. thx!

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is.  Are you trying to create a map application that includes other geographical information besides the basic Google Map tiles? Are you asking how to use the Google Terrain Tiles?

Comment: I want to import a map like this   http://ge-map-overlays.appspot.com/google-maps/terrain

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Google offers its Terrain tiles through the Google Maps API. There are other alternatives though. See [TopOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TopOSM)

But if you're looking to try to do something like the image you sent in the link above (in the comments).  You'll need your own map engine that can deal with elevation data and mapping the tiles over the elevations. This requires a 3d map.  You won't be able to do this with the Android Google Maps API. See [NASAs Worldwind Android](http://goworldwind.org/android/) for inspiration.